# Layout inflate exception on android 5.0 Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

i'm aware that this questions sounds very much like a lot of questions already made on this site, however, it's very different because of a simple reason, the apk DOES work, the main issue comes when i try to execute it on a device with android 5.0 or higher, i get this error:

> Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #46: Binary XML file line #46: Error inflating class com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContextView

this is the complete error log:

> 08-31 17:15:41.176 I/MonoDroid(16983): UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
>   08-31 17:15:41.228 I/MonoDroid(16983): Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #46: Binary XML file line #46: Error inflating class com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContextView ---> Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #46: Error inflating class com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContextView ---> Java.Lang.Reflect.InvocationTargetException: Exception of type 'Java.Lang.Reflect.InvocationTargetException' was thrown. ---> Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException: File res/drawable/fondo.jpg from drawable resource ID #0x7f020078: .xml extension required
>   08-31 17:15:41.228 I/MonoDroid(16983):    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   08-31 17:15:41.228 I/MonoDroid(16983):    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   08-31 17:15:41.228 I/MonoDroid(16983):    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   08-31 17:15:41.228 I/MonoDroid(16983):   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in :0 
>   08-31 17:15:41.228 I/MonoDroid(16983):   at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniObjectReference type, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00089] in <7802aa64ad574c33adca332a3fa9706a>:0 
>   08-31 17:15:41.228 I/MonoDroid(16983):   at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualVoidMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x0005d] in <7802aa64ad574c33adca332a3fa9706a>:0 
>   08-31 17:15:41.228 I/MonoDroid(16983):   at Android.App.Activity.SetContentView (System.Int32 layoutResID) [0x00022] in <263adecfa58f4c449f1ff56156d886fd>:0 
>   08-31 17:15:41.228 I/MonoDroid(16983):   at Pedidos.Order_Mobile.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle savedInstanceState) [0x00009] in C:\Users\Ricardo Vivas\source\repos\Pedidos\Pedidos\Order Mobile.cs:23 
>   08-31 17:15:41.228 I/MonoDroid(16983):   at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_savedInstanceState) [0x0000f] in <263adecfa58f4c449f1ff56156d886fd>:0 
>   08-31 17:15:41.228 I/MonoDroid(16983):   at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object.d2b532b9-063b-4cdb-8acc-161a755998d8(intptr,intptr,intptr)
>   08-31 17:15:41.228 I/MonoDroid(16983):   --- End of managed Android.Views.InflateException stack trace ---
>   08-31 17:15:41.228 I/MonoDroid(16983): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #46: Binary XML file line #46: Error inflating class com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContextView
>   08-31 17:15:41.228 I/MonoDroid(16983):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
>   08-31 17:15:41.228 I/MonoDroid(16983):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
>   08-31 17:15:41.228 I/MonoDroid(16983):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
>   08-31 17:15:41.228 I/MonoDroid(16983):  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:4000)
>   08-31 17:15:41.229 I/MonoDroid(16983):  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:4079)
>   08-31 17:15:41.229 I/MonoDroid(16983):  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:402)
>   08-31 17:15:41.229 I/MonoDroid(16983):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2191)
>   08-31 17:15:41.229 I/MonoDroid(16983):  at md5b750df5c4e09c9ddbc69b02eb7fa087e.Order_Mobile.n_onCreate(Native Method)
>   08-31 17:15:41.229 I/MonoDroid(16983):  at md5b750df5c4e09c9ddbc69b02eb7fa087e.Order_Mobile.onCreate(Order_Mobile.java:29)
>   08-31 17:15:41.229 I/MonoDroid(16983):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6309)
>   08-31 17:15:41.229 I/MonoDroid(16983):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113)
>   08-31 17:15:41.229 I/MonoDroid(16983):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2519)
>   08-31 17:15:41.229 I/MonoDroid(16983):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2654)
>   08-31 17:15:41.229 I/MonoDroid(16983):  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>   08-31 17:15:41.229 I/MonoDroid(16983):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1488)
>   08-31 17:15:41.229 I/MonoDroid(16983):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
>   08-31 17:15:41.229 I/MonoDroid(16983):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
>   08-31 17:15:41.229 I/MonoDroid(16983):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728)
>   08-31 17:15:41.229 I/MonoDroid(16983):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   08-31 17:15:41.229 I/MonoDroid(16983):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
>   08-31 17:15:41.229 I/MonoDroid(16983):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
>   08-31 17:15:41.229 I/MonoDroid(16983): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #46: Error inflating class com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContextView
>   An unhandled exception occured.
>
> 08-31 17:15:41.232 I/MonoDroid(16983):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
>   08-31 17:15:41.232 I/MonoDroid(16983):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
>   08-31 17:15:41.232 I/MonoDroid(16983):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
>   08-31 17:15:41.232 I/MonoDroid(16983):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
>   08-31 17:15:41.232 I/MonoDroid(16983):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
>   08-31 17:15:41.232 I/MonoDroid(16983):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
>   08-31 17:15:41.233 I/MonoDroid(16983):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
>   08-31 17:15:41.233 I/MonoDroid(16983):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
>   08-31 17:15:41.233 I/MonoDroid(16983):  ... 20 more
>   08-31 17:15:41.233 I/MonoDroid(16983): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>   08-31 17:15:41.233 I/MonoDroid(16983):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
>   08-31 17:15:41.234 I/MonoDroid(16983):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
>   08-31 17:15:41.234 I/MonoDroid(16983):  ... 27 more
>   08-31 17:15:41.234 I/MonoDroid(16983): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/fondo.jpg from drawable resource ID #0x7f020078: .xml extension required
>   08-31 17:15:41.234 I/MonoDroid(16983):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateListForCookie(Resources.java:2990)
>   08-31 17:15:41.234 I/MonoDroid(16983):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateList(Resources.java:2931)
>   08-31 17:15:41.234 I/MonoDroid(16983):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList(TypedArray.java:485)
>   08-31 17:15:41.234 I/MonoDroid(16983):  at android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable.updateGradientDrawableSolid(GradientDrawable.java:1320)
>   08-31 17:15:41.234 I/MonoDroid(16983):  at android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable.applyThemeChildElements(GradientDrawable.java:1148)
>   08-31 17:15:41.234 I/MonoDroid(16983):  at android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable.applyTheme(GradientDrawable.java:1056)
>   08-31 17:15:41.234 I/MonoDroid(16983):  at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.applyTheme(LayerDrawable.java:330)
>   08-31 17:15:41.234 I/MonoDroid(16983):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2765)
>   08-31 17:15:41.234 I/MonoDroid(16983):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:870)
>   08-31 17:15:41.234 I/MonoDroid(16983):  at android.view.View.(View.java:4001)
>   08-31 17:15:41.234 I/MonoDroid(16983):  at android.view.ViewGroup.(ViewGroup.java:604)
>   08-31 17:15:41.238 I/MonoDroid(16983):  at com.android.internal.widget.AbsActionBarView.(AbsActionBarView.java:70)
>   08-31 17:15:41.238 I/MonoDroid(16983):  at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContextView.(ActionBarContextView.java:83)
>   08-31 17:15:41.238 I/MonoDroid(16983):  at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContextView.(ActionBarContextView.java:78)
>   08-31 17:15:41.239 I/MonoDroid(16983):  at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContextView.(ActionBarContextView.java:74)
>   08-31 17:15:41.239 I/MonoDroid(16983):  ... 29 more

this is the layout i'm trying to call:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:p1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    p1:layout_width="match_parent"
    p1:layout_height="match_parent"
    p1:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    p1:weightSum="100"
    p1:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        p1:orientation="vertical"
        p1:minWidth="25px"
        p1:minHeight="25px"
        p1:layout_width="match_parent"
        p1:layout_height="0dp"
        p1:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        p1:background="#ff102563"
        p1:layout_weight="13"
        p1:layout_gravity="center"
        p1:gravity="center">
        <ImageView
            p1:src="@drawable/logoapp"
            p1:id="@+id/imageView1"
            p1:layout_width="match_parent"
            p1:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <Space
        p1:layout_width="match_parent"
        p1:layout_height="0dp"
        p1:id="@+id/space3"
        p1:layout_weight="20" />
    <LinearLayout
        p1:orientation="horizontal"
        p1:minWidth="25px"
        p1:minHeight="25px"
        p1:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        p1:layout_width="match_parent"
        p1:layout_height="0dp"
        p1:layout_weight="47"
        p1:weightSum="100">
        <Space
            p1:layout_width="0dp"
            p1:layout_height="match_parent"
            p1:id="@+id/space1"
            p1:layout_weight="20" />
        <ImageView
            p1:src="@drawable/logoinn2"
            p1:id="@+id/imageView2"
            p1:layout_width="0dp"
            p1:layout_height="match_parent"
            p1:layout_weight="60" />
        <Space
            p1:layout_width="0dp"
            p1:layout_height="match_parent"
            p1:id="@+id/space2"
            p1:layout_weight="20" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <Space
        p1:layout_width="match_parent"
        p1:layout_height="0dp"
        p1:id="@+id/space4"
        p1:layout_weight="20" />
</LinearLayout>
```

(i'm aware this construction method is inefficient, please disregard it)
this is the activity:

```
[Activity(Label = "Order Mobile", MainLauncher = true, Theme = "@style/NoActionBarTheme")]
    public class Order_Mobile : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Intro); (Error Here)
        ...
        }
```

just in case, this is the theme used for that view:

```
<style name="NoActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/invisible_action_bar_style</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#fff3f3f3</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">#ff102563</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/theme_custom_background</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">?android:attr/colorBackground</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#ff030303</item>
    <item name="android:colorButtonNormal">#ff1a237e</item>
    <item name="android:colorControlActivated">#ff3d5afe</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">#ff3f51b5</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">#ff1de9b6</item>
    <item name="android:colorControlNormal">#ffb2dfdb</item>
  </style>
  <style name="invisible_action_bar_style"     parent="android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:height">1dp</item>
  </style>
```

thanks in advance and excuse me if my post is inappropriate or deficient, this is my first time doing so

Comment: find `0x7f020078` in your R.java, what is it? is it `R.drawable.fondo`?

Comment: that's an image i used as a background for the layout

Comment: so what is it? `R.drawable.xxxx`? what is `xxxx`?

Comment: ?? i don't quite get what you're asking, the 0x7f020078 in the Resource.designer.cs is the reference for intellisense that targets the .jpg file "fondo", which i use for the backgrounds on ALL the layaouts in the project. the image is on a folder inside the project named "drawable" thus the reference is (Resource.drawable.fondo.jpg)...

Comment: tried to completely remove build folder and rebuild your project again?

Comment: yes, of course, in fact, i also created a new project altogether and migrated the .cs/.axml files there, same error, it won't work on android 5.0+

Comment: forget it, i already found the error, the theme can't set the backgroud from an image or an xml file from android 5.0+, it fires an inflate exception for some reason, i can just hard set the background on EVERY layout to avoid this error... thank you for your time... if someone knows how to set it with the theme please let me know...